# Questions must have a tag with 50+ questions - a good idea?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, tags

My suggestion is to mandatory have to include a tag wich has either 50+ questions (or better 100+ questions, my preference). I think this demand is reasonable.

Why do I want this? All the time in tag `interesting questions`, questions comes up with *only one tag, and that tag is a very rare tag*. `I'd like filter those out, not really possible`. (I have made a filter for questions with something of 500 keywords). This category of questions also involves tags wich simply is a synonym for a much more common tag i.e. [webkit.net](/questions/tagged/webkit.net) (26 questions) instead of [webkit](/questions/tagged/webkit) (3000+ questions).
  Examples of recent questions I've encountered with these rare tags are [this (1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578064), [this (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11571795) and [this (3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577864).
 Extra tags needed in these cases are.
 (1) "p2p", (2) "database", (3) "angstrom-linux".

Comment: This way no new languages / concepts could be handled by stackoverflow.

Comment: @örs They just would need an additional tag that's sufficiently often used. I'd expect there is a fitting one in the overwhelming majority of cases. But the remaining few are a problem.

Comment: @örs. That's bogus. If the fantasy language 'reprep' was to become in use you could tag the question 'reprep'+'programming-language'. Not hard at all.

Comment: @Olof Adler: [programming-language]? Seriously?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: Then I'd suggest you to come up with a better term. F.e. language 'rust' is rather recent. What else would you tag questions currently only tagged with 'rust' ??? Seriously. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust

Comment: @Olof Adler: Nothing else. Just [rust] by itself is fine for a question about... the Rust language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This suggestion seems very chicken and egg to me. When someone starts to program semantic zoom in Windows 8, how are they ever going to ask the first question here? There needs to be 50 questions first. How do the first 49 questions come into existence, if the first one needs a tag, which in turn needs 50 questions to already exist?

Answer (score 6):

In general, this would result in inappropriate tags being added just to meet the requirement. Every Java language library question would be tagged with "java", and every other library would be tagged with "c". I don't really think this would help, and it would be misleading: library questions shouldn't be tagged as the language that uses them, since they aren't  language questions. I think this would *hamper* filtering and search, rather than helping.

You would make your case more strongly if you could suggest additional tags for your three examples. As it stands, I don't see what other tags could apply, especially to the first two.

Comment: "library questions shouldn't be tagged as the language that uses them" unless of course the question involves working with said libraries in said languages, and so on. Posting this just to satisfy any pedants who might come along...